# How can I get a single value from an Array list?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, return-value

So I'm working on this program in where I need to sort the array list which contains items, the number of the item, total unit in stock, and the price. I already did this, the only problem I'm having is that I cannot find a way to get the total of the Array list by multiplying the total unit with the price.

My array list look something like this:

```
ArrayList< Inventory > a1 = new ArrayList<  >();

    a1.add(new Inventory("shoes", 1345, 134, 20.50f));
    a1.add(new Inventory("pies", 1732, 150, 3.35f));
    a1.add(new Inventory("cherries", 1143, 200, 4.40f));
    a1.add(new Inventory("shirt", 1575, 99, 10.60f));
    a1.add(new Inventory("beer", 1004, 120, 8.50f));
```

Now to evaluate the total, I tried putting it in my constructor class:

```
public float getTotal()
  {
      float total = 0.0f;

      return total += getUnit() * getPrice();  
  }
```

When I tried to use it in the main class, this is what I wrote:

```
Inventory[] array = new Inventory[a1.size()];
    Arrays.sort(a1.toArray(array));
    for (Inventory p : array)
        System.out.println(p);


    for(Inventory total: array)

    System.out.printf("The total of the Inventory is:$%.2f ", total.getTotal());
```

My problem is, the evaluation is going through every line and is outputting every single value of each line. I tried many other different for loops and I cannot get it to a single total value, which evaluates the entire array list. Can someone explain me how can I get it to a single value? I did it before, but when I changed the array list to be able to sort it, now I cannot get the single value again.

Oh! and this is in Netbeans for Java.

Thanks!

Comment: you have to create a local variable and store previous values when you are looping

Comment: In the first part of your question, you're talking about an `ArrayList` of `Inventory` objects. Then ... you're talking about sorting an array of them. Which in the end has nothing to do with totaling. I'm really not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @BrianRoach Well I don't know how to explain it, I'm new at this. I had a lot of  trouble finding out how to sort the list of items, which I had it written in some other way. I was able to get the total price of this list before, now that I arrange it, I cannot figure out how to get the total from this new list. I don't know if this makes it clear, if it doesn't, then please tell me how can I explain it. I really need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
Inventory[] array = new Inventory[a1.size()];
Arrays.sort(a1.toArray(array));
```

Can be acheived by this

```
Collections.sort(a1)
```

This will sort your list then you can just loop once to get total (I'm Assuming this is what you want)

```
float total = 0;
for(Inventory i: a1)
{
     total += i.getTotal();
     //if you want to print for every item, otherwise remove below line
     System.out.println(i)
}
System.out.println("The total is " + total); // This will just print one line 
                                             // with the total of the entrie list
```

**EDIT** You get doubled output because of this code

```
for (Inventory p : array)
    System.out.println(p);  // This prints every item in the list once

for(Inventory total: array) // And this is looping and printing again!
                            // This empty line does not matter, line below is looped
    System.out.printf("The total of the Inventory is:$%.2f ", total.getTotal());
```

Comment: This really worked. Although now my list output is doubled. What I mean is it appears twice, because I deleted the two lines; "Inventory[] array = new Inventory[a1.size()]" and Arrays.sort(a1.toArray(array));". I still have the same for loop to output the item list. I will continue trying until I get it and I will let you know. :)

Comment: You get doubled output because you are looping through the List twice! See edit

Comment: Oh! I got it thank you so much! I've been trying for more than a week, and I was finally solving everything until I got stuck on this small part. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. You should make this answer as accepted so people who find this post in the future know how it was resolved.

Comment: Ok, I might be posting a lot more questions in the future. I'm going to be learning a little more basics of Java, C and C++. I'm learning on my own, because I have no one to discuss this with, so even the vocabulary of programming, sometimes I find it a bit confusing, but hopefully I get it with time and practice. Thanks again ^w^

Comment: There is plenty of good tutorials out there for learning, Make sure to get familiar with [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) these are a programmers best friend next to a good IDE. Posting here is good for getting help also just make sure you try explain the question clearly and show what you have tried already. Also remember to always mark the answer as accepted when it works, this will make people more likely to answer your questions.

Comment: Ok I'll keep it in mind. I've been watching many tutorials, and reading a lot. I guess I'm just having some trouble learning something that is completely new to me, but I really like it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the total for each "Inventory" in the loop:

```
Inventory[] array = new Inventory[a1.size()];
Arrays.sort(a1.toArray(array));
float total = 0;
for (Inventory p : array)
{
    total += p.getTotal()
}
System.out.printf("The total of the Inventory is:$%.2f ", total);
```

Comment: You are welcome, when you are satisfied with an answer you should mark it as accepted. You should do the same in all your questions, that way people will know that you are interested, it is a way of getting involved with the community.